# Class Not Found in Module

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm working on a module which will modify the URLs for our category pages using a Magento 2 preference. I've created a module which looks correct, but on most pages the url is unchanged and on product pages it refuses to load, with apache reporting the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Company\\CategoryUrls\\Model\\Category' not found in [root folder]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

As far as I can see the module should be correct, and I know the change in behaviour works as I've tried editing it directly into the file in the vendors folder,but I just can't seem to get it to work. If anyone's got any suggestions it'd be appreciated

Module File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Company_CategoryUrls" setup_version="1.0.0" ></module>
</config>
```

DI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Company\CategoryUrls\Model\Category"/>
</config>
```

Class:

```
<?php

namespace Company\CategoryUrls\Model;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class CategoryUrl extends Category{
/**
 * Get category url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl()
{
[contents of parent class]
}
}
```

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command it will generate factory class again and then check. might it will help you

Comment: Unfortunately I'd made a mistake when renaming one of the classes and missed an instance of it, causing it not to find the class. Usually what you suggested does work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your preference file is expecting a called `Company\CategoryUrls\Model\Category` however your class is `Company\CategoryUrls\Model\CategoryUrl`.

You can either update your preference

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Company\CategoryUrls\Model\CategoryUrl"/>
 </config>
```

Or change your class name to be `Category`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, changed it previously to avoid a conflict but apparently missed one of the uses